# how to customize backgrid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backgrid

```
<script type="text/template" id="date-cell">
    <%= date.dateBegin %> até <%= date.dateEnd %>
    <br>
    <%= date.timeBegin %> até <%= date.timeEnd %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="status-cell">
    <% if (order.enable) { %>
        <% _.each(order.contacts, function(contact) { %>
            <span class="contact-type"><%= contact.value %></span>
        <% }); %>
    <% } else { %>
        <% if (order.expired) { %>
            <span class="label label-expired">Expirado</span>
        <% } else { %>
            <span class="label label-closed">Fechado</span>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var onRefreshGrid;

    $(function() {

        var Order,
            OrderCollection,
            orders,
            grid;

        Order = Backbone.Model.extend({});

        OrderCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            modal: Order,
            url: 'http://localhost:2000/orders.php'
        });

        orders = new OrderCollection();

        var columns = [{
            name : "hash",
            label: "Cod. Pedido",
            cell : 'string',
            editable: false
          },
          {
            name : "user",
            label: "Nome",
            cell: "string",
            editable: false
          },
          {
            name : "order",
            label: "Status",
            cell : Backgrid.StringCell.extend({
                template: _.template($('#status-cell').html()),
                render: function () {
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
                    return this;
                }
            }),
            editable: false
          },
          {
            name : "date",
            label: "Data",
            cell: Backgrid.StringCell.extend({
                template: _.template(
                    $('#date-cell').html()
                ),
                render: function() {
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
                    return this;
                }
            }),
            editable: false
        }];

        // Initialize a new Grid instance
        grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
            columns: columns,
            collection: orders
        });

        // Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document
        $('#datagrid').append(grid.render().el);

        onRefreshGrid = function () {
            orders.fetch({});
        };

        // auto execute
        onRefreshGrid();

    });
</script>
```

I need to add a background-color to each row (tr) according to a condition, was looking at the documentation met "Backgrid.Row.extend" what you can do, just that I need to create a base template .. that would replicate in each row (tr), just that I also have some columns costumizo as the code shows. 
My question is .. You can add an event to listen to each line and I can only change its attributes without disrupting the structure (html)?

Comment: Anything you want to do. To fix classes in Backgrid currently is an AWFUL HACK:

https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid/issues/465

Answer (score 4):

Every Row or Cell instance will have access to the entire model. You can access them from within your `render` method and add your CSS classes there. Something like this will do:

```
var MyRow = Backgrid.Row.extend({
  render: function () {
    MyRow.__super__.render.apply(this, arguments);
    if (this.model.get("someAttribute")) {
      this.el.classList.add("aClass");
    }
    return this;
  }
});
```

A row is a row, they are all the same. No need to use a template.

Comment: Hello from thank you! I tried to apply your suggestion, most had this error in return:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined backgrid.min.js:8

Comment: happens that I had mentioned in the original topic, the template is blank.
without the customization of row the grid is filled.

Comment: I'm sorry I have trouble understanding you. Did you read the documentation? You have to pass the MyRow class to the grid's constructor.

Comment: excuse me for the english! I did just that: [Look the gist](https://gist.github.com/hugohenrique/8585447)

Comment: Just edited the answer again. I forgot to call super. This should work now.